# Creating and Visualizing samples in R

Tags: r, sampling

I want to create 100 samples from a normal distribution. For the first class, the mean is to be taken as `(0,0)` and covariance matrix as `[(1,0),(0,1)]`. For the second class, the mean is to be taken as `(5,0)` but the covariance matrix is the same as for the first class and finally would like to visualize all `200` instances in a single plot with different colors for each class.

My problem is: When I generate this plot I am unsure about the final plot whether it actually has a volume of `200` samples.

My approach:

```
a1 <- c(1,0)
a2 <- c(0,1)

M <- cbind(a1, a2)
x <- cov(M)
dev <- sd(x, na.rm = FALSE)

C0 <- sample(rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=dev), size=100, replace=T)
C1 <-  sample(rnorm(100, mean=5, sd=dev), size=100, replace=T)

plot(C0,C1, col=c("red","blue"), main = '200 samples, with mean 0 and 5 and S.D=0.5')
legend("topright", 95, legend=c("C0", "C1"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=1:2, cex=0.8)
```

I would like to know the corrections in my code.

[plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUoWY.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the plotting issue mentioned in the other answer, it seems from your description like you want to sample from two 2D multivariate normal distributions with different means.

If so, you can simply use the `mvtnorm` library to sample from these distributions, which is the multivariate normal distribution.

```r
library(mvtnorm)
C0 <- rmvnorm(100, c(0,0), M) # 100 samples, means (0, 0), covariance mtx M
C1 <- rmvnorm(100, c(5,0), M)
```

Right now, you take the covariance *of the* covariance matrix you have by typing `x <- cov(M)`. This doesn't make much sense unless I'm misunderstanding what you're trying to accomplish.

---

EDIT: This is the full code for what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```r
a1 <- c(1, 0)
a2 <- c(0, 1)
M <- cbind(a1, a2)

C0 <- rmvnorm(100, c(0, 0), M)
C1 <- rmvnorm(100, c(5, 0), M)

plot(C0, col = "red", xlim = c(-5, 10), ylim = c(-5, 5), xlab = "X", ylab = "Y")
points(C1, col = "blue")
legend("topright", inset = .05, c("Class 1", "Class 2"), fill = c("red", "blue"))
```

which outputs the plot

[image: class plot]

Answer (score 1):

Your x and y axes demonstrate that you're plotting C1 against C0. That's why your y-axis has its midpoint at 5 and the x-axis has it at 0. What you've done is plot 100 points with their x-coordinate from C0 and y-coordinate from C1.

Short of counting them, proving that you have 100 points on the screen is difficult. I know of no way to access the data that R has used to display your plot. However, one trick is to call `text(C0,C1,label=1:150)` after your code. This adds the numbers 1:150 to your plot, with each number having a corresponding label. If you had 200 points, this would be a tidy plot. However, since you have 100, many are labelled twice, making the plot unreadable.
[image]
If we make a new plot and use `text(C0,C1,label=1:100)` instead, things are much more clear:
[image]

Comment: Yep, I now understand there are many more things to learn!